# Measuring cellular strength in Ionic Framework

Tags: ionic-framework, ios11, signal-strength

In the Ionic framework, is there a way to read the current cellular signal strength & other data (currently connected tower, band, etc..) via the Ionic APi?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ionic is a frontend framework so *no* you can't read low level network related data via its API. Also if you are referring to ionic-native, thats only a wrapper around the APIs exposed by different cordova plugins to provide some convenience features such as autocomplete, promise-callbacks and change-detection out of the box.

What you can do is searching for a cordova-plugin which can deliver this kind of information (for example: [cordova-plugin-signal-strength](https://github.com/petervojtek/cordova-plugin-signal-strength) (Android only)). Another possibility is to create your own plugin and implement the native parts yourself.